# get-casmailbox (Powershell) functionality in EWS API (C#)?

Tags: c#, powershell, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

Hopefully a simple question. In the Exchange Powershell API, there are functions such as "get-casmailbox" to set a mailbox to be accessible via OWA, etc. I am trying to integrate this type of functionality in to a C# program, and it is absurd to call Powershell in C# just to interact with Exchange.

I have successfully added the EWS API, but cannot find such functionality like get-casmailbox.

Is there an alternative, or am I stuck with doing get-casmailbox and set-casmailbox in Powershell only?

Answer (score 0):

I think it is absolutely okay to use Powershell as it is the only interface to administer Exchange Settings in a reliable way.

You could look at the protocolSettings Attribute of the user - these settings are stored there. But I absolutely do not recommend to change them directly. (Although it might work)

Enjoy -tom